# Proper formatting in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I keep getting inverted commas around printed expressions when I do for example:

```
{{record.FirstName}}
```

when the field is:

```
FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

How should I do this? I have tried:

```
record.MyLinkedInFirstName.__str__()
```

but this fails.

When I simply do as above in the template I get "Fred", when I'd like just Fred. In the shell. If I do record.MyLinkedInFirstName, I get u'Fred' but if I ad **str** in shell I get 'Fred'. Here is my template:

```
{% for record in list %}
  {{ record.MyLinkedInFirstName }} 
{% endfor %}
```

and view:

```
list = AboutMe.objects.all()    
return render(request, 'list.html', {'list': list, 'loggedin': loggedin})
```

Comment: Is that part of `FirstName` in the record?

Comment: What do you get when you load the same record in a Python shell (`python manage.py shell`) and type `record.FirstName`? What output do you get in your browser?

Comment: You'll need to show more of the template, and probably the view too. Django variable tags don't automatically add quotes, so you're doing something unusual.